# What is the best way to backup large objects?

Tags: c#, performance, real-time

I have an object (List) that contains around 10,000,000 records, I want to save them to the disk (or somewhere else?) in real-time and load them when my app comes up (in case it was crashed or something)

What is the best way to do it fast?

Answer (score 2):

As answered by Tigran, if you require a full database or only want to perform changes to the data, go for Sqlite or [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx).

If however, you simply want to save and restore the list in its entirety, you could use [serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to save it to a file.

Comment: How will the serialization work with so many records? in terms of speed. Everything should be real-time.

Comment: How large are your records?

Comment: To write 10000000 integers to a file on a normal HDD it takes my machine ~6 seconds. However remember, you could perform the serialization using TPL and not block your primary thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) to save it on disk in fully featured ACID database.

No services, just a library you have and a file you create on the disk .

Comment: what is special with this? i can write a simple binary file and read when needed. Please throw some light.

Comment: It's fulle featured ACID database, which means you have built in support for Atomicity, Consisitency, Isolation and Durability of your data and flow of that data. If you do it by yourself you have to implement relibility features by yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot. i will read up. anything you suggest to read up on databases in c#? would be a great help. thanks

Comment: @Naresh: check out this article for example targeting SQLite use in C#: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application